# System.Threading.Timer не существует в пространстве имен

Tags: c#, таймер, xamarin

Хотел реализовать простенький таймер в C#, но столкнулся с тем, что компилятор никак не может увидеть класс Timer:

> Ошибка    CS0234  Тип или имя пространства имен "Timer" не существует в
>   пространстве имен "System.Threading" (возможно, отсутствует ссылка на
>   сборку)

В чем может быть проблема?

27.07.15: Забыл добавить, что разработка идет на Xamarin.Forms...

Comment: Проект не для Windows Store, случаем?

Comment: Нужно чуть по подробнее раскрывать суть проблемы!  Обязательно этот таймер использовать?A лучше кусок кода увидеть где вы реализуете таймер!

Comment: Объект System.Threading.Timer — простой таймер, использующий методы ответного вызова, который обслуживается потоками пула. Не рекомендуется использовать этот объект с Windows Forms, поскольку обратные вызовы не происходят в потоках пользовательского интерфейса. Более удобным вариантом для использования с Windows Forms является объект System.Windows.Forms.Timer. Для функций таймера, базирующихся на сервере, можно использовать System.Timers.Timer, который управляет событиями и обладает дополнительными функциями.

Comment: @IGOR Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 3):

В проекте используется PCL-библиотека, в которой доступно только некоторое подмножество .NET. Функциональность, реализация которой платформозависима, как, например, у System.Threading.Timer, не включена в PCL.

---

Возможные варианты:

- В Xamarin.Forms можно воспользоваться [Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3AXamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer)
- Использовать метод [System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh194873%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151143/pcl-net-4-5-timer)
- Сделать свою реализацию таймера на основе Task.Delay как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555049/timer-in-portable-library)
- Или, достаточно радикально: использовать Shared Library вместо PCL для проекта